# Steps to install Psiphon 3 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, proxy

I want to install Psiphon on my system running Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried running the .exe using wine but it does not work a new window opens and gets stuck with a white screen.

It would also be helpful if someone could suggest an alternative for Linux which works exactly like Psiphon (I've already tried Tor and it does not work for me.)

Comment: I tried those steps but when i run exe using wine it gets stuck after opening a new window.

Comment: Any use? [Alternative for psiphon for Ubuntu 14.04](//askubuntu.com/q/801624)

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))